# App Engine; File referenced by handler not found: main.py

Tags: google-app-engine

First post here at stack overflow. Please forgive my posting errors.
I have spent a lot of time at this. I started with the 500 server error.

This long is stating python not found.  My app is JS, CSS, and HTML only. (at this point) I have included the yaml, because I cant rule out for myself if I have errors there through my research.

Pointers are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

My `app.yaml`:

```
   application: application
    version: secureable
    runtime: python27
    api_version: 1
    threadsafe: false

    handlers:
    - url: /(.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))
      static_files: \1
      upload: (.*\.(gif|png|jpg|ico|js|css))

    - url: /robots.txt
      static_files: robots.txt
      upload: robots.txt 

    - url: .*
      script: main.py

    inbound_services:
    - mail
```

The error:

```
     httpRequest: {
      status: 500   

   0: {
    logMessage: "File referenced by handler not found: main.py"     
    severity: "WARNING"     
    time: "2017-09-24T21:12:30.191830Z"     
   }
  ]
  megaCycles: "2"   
  method: "GET"   
     requestId:   resource: "/index.html"   
  startTime: "2017-09-24T21:12:30.138333Z"   
  status: 500   
  traceId: "618d060203d57aea2bfddc905e350698"   
  urlMapEntry: "main.py"   
  userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0)       Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"   
  versionId: "secureable"   
 }
 receiveTimestamp: "2017-09-24T21:12:30.926277443Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   module_id: "default"    
   project_id: "Application"    
   version_id: "secureable"    
   zone: "us9"    
  }
   type: "gae_app"   
  }
 severity: "WARNING"  
 timestamp: "2017-09-24T21:12:30.138333Z"  
}
```

Comment: Quess I should have included this is an app  engine deployment,  Uploads fine. Says its serving, but the URL returns only "contact admin, or try again in 30 seconds". Error 500 code as stated.

Answer (score 2):

If your app is only HTML, CSS, and JS, you can remove the catch-all pointer to the Python script all together and instead use an `app.yaml` format like the one shown in the [Hosting a Static Website on App Engine tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/hosting-a-static-website#creating_the_appyaml_file):

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: www/\1
  upload: www/(.*)
```

Later if you want to add server-side logic with a Python module, you can add in a handler with a `script` associated with it. When you take that step, you use an import style pointer in the form of `[script_name].[var_pointing_to_wsgi_application_in_script]`. So if you have `main.py` and within that a variable called `application` that is set to your WSGI application, then you would use `script: main.application`.

Commonly a WSGI application is either webapp2 ([example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/hello_world/main.py#L24)) or Flask ([example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/flask/hello_world/main.py#L21)).

Answer (score 1):

Your `script: main.py` statement in the `handlers` section of the `app.yaml` file is wrong, it should be `script: main.app`.

From the `script` row in the [Handlers element](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref#handlers_element) table (sadly not properly formatted, including the quote from the page source to make it readable):

> **script**
>
> A `script:` directive must be a python import path, for example,
>   `package.module.app` that points to a WSGI application. The last
>   component of a `script:` directive using a **Python module** path is
>   the name of a global variable in the module: that variable must be a
>   WSGI app, and is usually called `app` by convention.